# Type Conversion and Operator Compatibility

Tags: solidity

[image]

The code snippet I have included Converts an ASCII string value into an `uint` as long as the string itself is a valid unsigned integer and I am getting errors on line "assert(uint8(_bytesValue[i]) >= 48 && uint8(_bytesValue[i]) <= 57);" and on line "_ret += (uint8(_bytesValue[i]) - 48)*j;" as given in the screenshot of the code.

```
function parseInt(string memory _value) 
    public
    returns (uint _ret) {
    bytes memory _bytesValue = bytes(_value);
    uint j = 1;
    for(uint i = _bytesValue.length-1; i >= 0 && i < _bytesValue.length; i--) 
    {
        assert(uint8(_bytesValue[i]) >= 48 && uint8(_bytesValue[i]) <= 57);
        _ret += (uint8(_bytesValue[i]) - 48)*j;
        j*=10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code and the errors you get (not a screenshot).

Comment: Ok... i have edited the body... please look at it

Answer (score 2):

You can cast a `bytes1` to a `uint8` and then compare.  For example:

```
bytes memory _bytesValue = bytes('yo yo');
assert(uint8(_bytesValue[2]) >= 4);
uint _ret = uint8(_bytesValue[2]) - 4;
```

Comment: You should probably choose this answer then.

Comment: There is no `byte1` type in Solidity.  It is named `bytes1`.

Answer (score 1):

When reading one element from a `bytes`, you get a `bytes1`.

You should probably cast your `bytes1` to a `uint8`